# Hide Scrollbars in Eclipse Editors

Tags: eclipse, gui

I like Eclipse a lot, but I would like some way to easily hide the scrollbars in the Eclipse editors.  I have seen this eclipse bug [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27096), but don't know what to make of it (if it has been solved, why do I still see the scrollbars?). I am aware of the [fullscreen plugin](http://code.google.com/p/eclipse-fullscreen/), however I would like for the horizontal and vertical bars to be either always hidden, or even better automatically hidden when they are not needed. Does anyone know of a plugin or configuration file where I could set this?  Thanks!

I would like to be able to do this in both Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you by anychance were developing in [Python](http://pydev.org/), PyDev is a Python IDE/plugin for Eclipse that has an option to show/hide scrollbars in the (python) editor.

Go to `Preferences > PyDev > Editor > Overview Ruler Minimap`.
There is an option `Show vertical scrollbar?` ([see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT2Yx.png))

Refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25678783/2448645) to [where is classical vertical scrollbar in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25594935/where-is-classical-vertical-scrollbar-in-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

For all mac users out there, you can change it in system preferences:
Apple menu > System Preferences, then click General > Show scroll bars
Select “Automatically based on mouse or trackpad.” i voila :)